# how to compute the centroid of the PointCloud2

Tags: pcl, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am considering how can I compute the centroid of sensor_msgs/PointCloud2, is there a direct way to do this? Because I only find he pcl::CentroidPoint< PointT > Class Template Reference *[link text] (http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_centroid_point.html#details) on the website.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308439/how-to-compute-the-centroid-of-the-pointcloud2/) by [zhonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/38441/zhonghao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll first need to convert the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 into a pcl::PointCloud object as below. Note you may have to change to type of the point cloud to match what you have.

```
#include <pcl/conversions.h>

...

pcl::PCLPointCloud2 point_cloud2;  // Input PointCloud2 message
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> pclObj;  // pcl version of the point cloud
 
// Do the conversion
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2( point_cloud2, pclObj);
```

Now you can loop through the `pclObj.points` vector adding them to a `pcl::CentroidPoint` object and then extract the centroid at the end. I Don't think there's a direct method to get the centroid from the PointCloud2 message itself.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on 2019-05-05**:
Hi! I am trying to convert an image in a point cloud using PCL and I am using the code's lines that you have written; but my input is different, so I don't know how to change the line:

```
pcl::PCLPointCloud2 point_cloud2;
```

How can I using an image as input instead of sensor_msgs/PointCloud2?
Consider that I have a frame with all necessary informations (intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of camera, depth, and so on).
Thanks!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-06**:
Please can you ask a new question instead of tagging on to the end of this one.